# Android OpenGL: DrawElements for large, complex 3d objects

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, opengl-es

In an app I am currently working on on Android, OpenGL 3.0, I have a complex, large object with about 80000-90000 vertices and hundreds of thousands of triangles. This object exists along with a lot of other, significantly smaller and less complex objects.

With 80000-90000 vertices, I had to use GL_UNSIGNED_INT and an IntBuffer for the index data, and initially, I used these parameters for drawElements() and called drawElements() once. The object rendered correctly, but my fps was visibly and significantly decreased. I took a wild shot at correcting the issue and basically broke up that one drawElements call into 6 drawElements calls, breaking up my IntBuffer into 6 pieces. So this is how my code looked:

Initially:

`GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffer);`

After my change:

`GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length/6, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffers[0]);`

`GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length/6, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffers[1]);`

`GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length/6, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffers[2]);`

`GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length/6, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffers[3]);`

`GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length/6, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffers[4]);`

`GLES30.glDrawElements(GLES30.GL_TRIANGLES, indices.length/6, GLES30.GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indexBuffers[5]);`

Where indexBuffers[] is an array of IntBuffers containing my IntBuffer split up into 6 pieces.

Somehow, breaking up the drawElements call sped up my app, and my fps greatly improved.

Why is this the case? Can anyone explain why breaking up the call (but still making each call one after another successively) is faster than make one big call? Does it have something to do with the thread mechanisms of OpenGL?

My completely uneducated, wild guess, is that making a drawElements call is like starting a new thread. Therefore, splitting the call will divide the work amongst a set of threads. Is this correct?

Comment: Not directly answering to the question, but I would strongly urge you to use VBOs for your data instead of client side buffers. Particularly with large amounts of data, it should be much more efficient. Using client side buffers is also marked as a legacy feature in ES 3.0, and might be removed in the future.

Comment: Thanks, I am completely new to computer graphics and I didn't realize the differences between client-side buffers and VBOs. I had assumed that since I had been using VBOs all along, but http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-seven-an-introduction-to-vertex-buffer-objects-vbos/ has taught me otherwise. Also, after reading the article I posted above, do you think there is any performance advantage to using packed buffers (meaning that my vertices, indices, normals, and textures are all in one buffer?). Do you think it would be significant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using VBOs for vertex data, neither for index data.

So, simplifying, this means the following: each time you do a glDrawElements, all the vertex and index data have to be copied from "CPU to GPU" / "RAM to VRAM" before the GPU can start drawing anything.

This "copying" is done on the CPU side (by the GLES driver) and once it is done the GPU can start the rendering, in parallel of CPU future processings. So while the CPU is copying the GPU is basically IDLE (except if it is still busy rendering previous draw calls). Of course the more vertices/indices you have, the more time it will take to do this "copy".

So now here is what I think happens,

When you do a unique draw call, at each frame :

1. CPU sends/copy 80000 vertices + indices to GPU, during this GPU is IDLE
2. GPU starts to render

when you do 6 draw calls :

1. CPU sends/copy (80000/6) vertices + indices to GPU, GPU is IDLE
2. CPU sends/copy (80000/6) vertices + indices to GPU, GPU is rendering 1.
3. CPU sends/copy (80000/6) vertices + indices to GPU, GPU is rendering 1 / 2.
4. CPU sends/copy (80000/6) vertices + indices to GPU, GPU is rendering 1 / 2 / 3.
5. etc.

So you get a better CPU/GPU parallelisation by splitting in 6 draw calls, but this is because : you are not using VBOs and your scene probably not very complex (in terms of draw call count and shader cycle count).

When using VBOs, this copy" operation is not needed, so things are much faster and splitting in multiple draw calls should gain no performance.

PS: It would be great that you specifiy on which Android device you are testing as there are at least 5 different GPU brands (Adreno, Mali, Nvidia, Power VR, Vivante) in the Android "jungle" so the behavior can be very different depending on the phone.

Comment: Thanks, I am completely new to computer graphics and I didn't realize the differences between client-side buffers and VBOs. I had assumed that since I had been using VBOs all along, but http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-seven-an-introduction-to-vertex-buffer-objects-vbos/ has taught me otherwise.